# Undefined argument in option spec

Tags: perl

I am writing perl code by komodo ide in my open suse os.

In command line I pass:

```
--verbose --verbose -v --more --lib='/lib' -l '/lib64' -f a=1 --flag b=2  --debug 2 -t fukai
```

to my script that has following code:

```
use Getopt::Long;
use Smart::Comments;

my @libs = ();
my %flags = ();
my ($verbose, $all, $more, $diam, $debug, $test, $step);

GetOptions(
   'verbose+' => \$verbose,
   'more!' => \$more,
   'debug:i' => \$debug,
   'lib=s' => \@libs,
   'flag=s' => \%flags,
   'test|t' => \$test,
   'all|everything|universe' => $all
);
    
### $verbose
### $more
### $debug
### $test
### @libs;
### %flags
```

I get error:

```
Undefined argument in option spec
```

Comment: Seems like there is a missing backslash in front of `$all`. It should be `'all|everything|universe' => \$all`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
'all|everything|universe' => $all
```

should be

```
'all|everything|universe' => \$all
```

Comment: Ok, it is my mistake. Thanks